# AWS s3 - How to serve different file based on url parameter

Tags: amazon-s3

For legacy reasons I need to serve different files from amazon s3 based on query string parameters. For example myfile.php?type=1 should serve other file than myfile.php?type=2. the files themselves are static.

I successfuly created in a bucket a file named myfile.php?type=1 using S3 php class. But when I try to access it from a browser I get "Access Denied" xml. If I create a file named myfile.php in the same bucket it is accessed when I call myfile.php?type=1 instead of the actual myfile.php?type=1.

How can I make myfile.php?type=1 and myfile.php?type=2 access different files?

Thanks,
Niro

Answer (score 1):

Try to URL encode the ? and = signs.